# FFMPEG - Overlay stop updating after few minutes

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, rtsp

First im sorry for my english :-(

I do streaming from RTSP to Facebook live (RTMP).
I overlay PNG file, on the stream left corner, with score information and time (like tv soccer match).

After few minutes, the image overlay dont refresh, and i dont know why...
Image is updated by vbscript, and its correctly done.

This is my code :

```
cmd.exe /K ffmpeg.exe ^
-f lavfi -y ^
-i anullsrc -rtsp_transport tcp ^
-i "rtsp://xxx:xxx@xxx:8080/videoMain" ^
-r 1 -loop 1 -f image2pipe -i 762141_marquage.png ^
-filter_complex "[2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a];[1:v][a]overlay=10:10" ^
-tune zerolatency -vcodec libx264 -c:v libx264 -crf 30 -preset ultrafast -c:a aac -strict experimental ^
-f flv "rtmp://xxx"
```

Some one can help me ? please :-)

Comment: The update has to be atomic. Change `-r 1` to `-re -framerate 1` to limit the read frequency.

Comment: Thanks @Gyan, but how can i update the file in vbscript or vb.net ? Just do a simple "replace file" ?

Comment: Write to a temp image and then move the temp to the ffmpeg input file.